# sticker pack iOS ipad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, xcode8

I am in the process of submitting a sticker pack to the App Store. I built the sticker pack using the Xcode sticker pack template. I didn't change anything in the code. I simply added the stickers and the app icons. My sticker pack was rejected with the following message. I was hoping someone could guide me in fixing this issue.

This is the message that I received: 
From Apple
Guideline 2.3 - Performance

We were unable to install the app on iPad Air 2. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist appears to be set in such a way that the app will not install on this device .

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.

Resources

Please review the Technical Q&A 1397: Understanding the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key for information on the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.

You may also wish to review the dictionary keys table in the "Declaring the Required Device Capabilities" section of the App Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: Two thoughts. (1) Assuming by stating *"I didn't change anything in the code"* you mean you haven't changed anything in info.plist, what version of Xcode are you using? (2) Could you provide what the current value for the *UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities* key is?

Comment: 1) I am using Xcode version 8.3. 2) In info.plist the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key is set to armv7. Thank you for your help. Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: I couldn't find anything.I tried a "basic" sticker app and got the same plist setting as you. I was surprised that you don't designate which devices you are targeting (you even do that for a photo editing extension). Maybe the review was faulty - maybe you can resubmit and add a detailed note for the reviewer. In case you haven't seen this, here's a link detailing various architecture targets: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen the architecture targets. Thank you for your help. Ill try resubmitting and Ill let you know what happens. I really appreciate your attempt.